# Group by date without time in Firebird

Tags: sql, group-by, casting, firebird

I want grouping sales in day-to-day from Firebird table.

I have written SQL statement in this way.

```
SELECT CAST(STARTTIME AS DATE)
FROM TESTTABLE
GROUP BY CAST(STARTTIME AS DATE)
```

It is giving an error

```
Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 3, char 10 CAST
```

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? Your query works just fine in Firebird 2.1, Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3.

Comment: I am using Firebird 2.5.2, but it doesn't work. But works @ravioli 's first code fine. Thanks...

Comment: Why are you still using Firebird 2.5.2? That version is almost 7 years old. Firebird 2.5.9 is the last version of 2.5.x, and Firebird 3.0.4 is the current latest version.

Comment: However, I just installed Firebird 2.5.2 and I'm unable to reproduce the error with your query. It works for me.

Comment: I just tested with earlier versions, and your query also works with Firebird 2.0, but doesn't work with Firebird 1.5 (and presumably earlier). That would mean that you aren't using Firebird 2.5.2, but actually are using Firebird 1.5 (or possibly InterBase).

Comment: I have to use this version because accounting program written on this version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
SELECT src.STARTDATE
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(STARTTIME AS DATE) AS STARTDATE
    FROM TESTTABLE
) src
GROUP BY src.STARTDATE
```

If this is all you want, logically what you are doing is the same as a `DISTINCT`.  you could even do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(STARTTIME AS DATE)
FROM TESTTABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query works under Firebird 2.0, Firebird 2.1, Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3.0. It doesn't work under Firebird 1.5 and earlier.

In addition to the answer provided by ravioli, you could also apply the following workarounds:

Use column index in `group by`

```
SELECT CAST(STARTTIME AS DATE)
FROM TESTTABLE
GROUP BY 1
```

Use column alias in `group by`

```
SELECT CAST(STARTTIME AS DATE) AS ALIAS
FROM TESTTABLE
GROUP BY ALIAS
```

Comment: It works as it is, but cast does not work with group by

Comment: @zokanzi I tested it, and `cast` in a `group by` is valid in Firebird 2.0 and higher. You are either using Firebird 1.5 or earlier, or something else is going on.

Comment: I am sure Firebird version 2.5.2. Maybe I typed the transaction incorrectly. I will simply test it in my free time. Thanks for your help.